# Drone recommended for quality shooting but for non-experts

Tags: recommendations, video, photography

I would need to buy a serious drone to make quality videos and footage. However, searching online there is a lot of stuff that is passed off as *"better than others"*.

Could someone recommend a drone that is simple to use and is able to:

1. Shoot at a quality of at least 1080p 60fps
2. Have macros to follow a
   subject
3. The drone should be durable and smart (avoid obstacles)
4. Particularly resistant to sand and wind

I would need not to spend too much so if you can recommend me the best quality/ price ratio drone with these pretty general features I would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the niche that DJI have dominated. Near professional level features but easy to learn. They're not priced as 'toys' but they're a lot cheaper than professional gear.

I'm not an expert in their various models, but features like following a subject and obstacle avoidance are quite advanced and rule out most of the cheaper copycat drones.

'Real' TV and movie filming will use much more expensive drones that require a lot more knowledge and experience, but it seems that any youtuber can buy a Mavic and produce great shots after skimming the manual.

At the other end of the scale, there are cheaper options but none of them are nearly as popular. Either they don't have the same features, just don't work as well or they aren't as easy to use. There are a lot of cheap imitations aimed at people who don't do much research. They look similar and claim similar features for a lot less, but are missing features you don't realise are important, or just aren't much good.